# Ext JS 6 Migration from Ext JS 4.1.3

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

We are using Ext JS 4.1.3 in our application. Now we want to migrate to the latest Ext JS 6. We are seeing the JS code changes for the same.

However, I want to know the changes that may have to be done in the CSS in my application.
Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Recently , We have done migration from ExtJS 4.1.3 to ExtJS 6.0.1..I will suggest you, if you are doing up gradation ..do for latest one which has more fixes...And about your question..Changes to css means what exactly you looking for ?

Comment: I want to know what are the enhancements that have been done in Ext JS 6 in styling and theming specifically. 
And what changes will I have to do in my application in CSS properties or structure, if any (it right now runs on Ext JS 4.1.3 and CSS 3)

Answer (score 1):

The question is too broad. There are zillions of things that have changed in the CSS between 5.1.x and 6.0.x alone. I would recommend that you have a look at ["ExtJS 6 Theming Guide"](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/core_concepts/theming.html), the ["Sencha Fashion Guide"](https://www.sencha.com/blog/how-to-style-apps-with-fashion-in-ext-js-6/) and [the new Crisp and Triton themes](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/classic/themes/index.html) first; and then try to port your code and your CSS. Should specific questions arise during port, you can ask here.